# Flag MySQL table records based on a second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
Table A has a list of records.

```
RecordID  DateTime              ClientID
1         2017-07-01 17:20:21   1
2         2017-07-01 17:01:41   2
3         2017-07-01 17:20:30   1
4         2017-07-01 17:10:23   2
5         2017-07-01 17:01:20   2
6         2017-07-01 17:15:11   2
....
```

Table B holds a number of valid records for the client.

```
ClientID  Date          ValidRecords
1         2017-07-01    1
2         2017-07-01    2
```

I need a query which takes the number (n) from table B and flag (1 or 0) that amount (n) of records in table A.

The expected result:

```
RecordID  DateTime              ClientID    Valid
1         2017-07-01 17:20:21   1           1
2         2017-07-01 17:01:41   2           1
3         2017-07-01 17:20:30   1           0
4         2017-07-01 17:10:23   2           1
5         2017-07-01 17:01:20   2           0
6         2017-07-01 17:15:11   2           0
```

Client 1 has one correct record, the other one is 0. 
Client 2 has two correct records, so others should be marked 0.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I believe this would be far easier to do in code as part of a scheduled job that accesses the database than to try to do in the database itself.

Comment: How do you determine which one is valid among the two records of client 1?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus well in a real world with a real data all this would go into a tabular cube...

Comment: @azalea One of the following ideas is to sort 1st table by date and update first n records as valid while others would be 0

Answer (score 0):

this is an example:

**My tables:**

```
Table A
------------------
id | name |
 1 | beer |
 2 | wine |
------------------
table B
-----------------
id | id_table_a
1  | 1
```

**THE RESULT:**

```
-------------------------------
id | name | id_table_a | flag |
 1 | beer | 1          | 1    |
 2 | wine | Null       | 0    |
-------------------------------
```

**QUERY:**

```
select a.*, b.id_table_a, case when b.id is null then 0 else 1 end as flag 
from tablea a
left join tableb b on a.id = b.id_table_a
```